# Product page as homepage in Opencart

Tags: php, html, content-management-system, opencart

I have only one product on my opencart and I want this product just to be in the homepage so that the customer will no longer go to any page just to buy the product. How can I make this product as default homepage? or How can I make the url default to the url of this product? I'm using opencart. I've tried to override the layout of the product but it didn't work. "Opencart Admin > Product > Porduct Page > Layout Tab > Override (Home)".

Comment: Which version of OpenCart are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.5.6. @GeorgeQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these require you to edit your `/catalog/controller/common/home.php` and place the code after the `public function index() {` line, changing 123 to your products id

### v1.5.x

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=123'));
```

### v2.x + v3.x

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=123'));
```

Comment: This worked, but what if I have multistore and only one store will redirect to that link?

Comment: @JayGilford I think he wants only 1 store to redirect

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the homepage URL and display the product you can edit the `/index.php` file and add the following code

```
if (!isset($request->get['route']) || $request->get['route'] == 'common/home')   {
    $request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
    $request->get['product_id'] = 1;
}
```

Add it below the code

```
// SEO URL's
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/seo_url'));
```

You will need to change the product_id to the id of your product. e.g. `$request->get['product_id'] = 12;`

Comment: What if I have multistore and only one store will redirect to that link?

Comment: If you only want to do this to one store you can change the if statement to `if ($config->get('config_store_id') == 1 && $request->get['route']) || $request->get['route'] == 'common/home')   {` and change the id (shown as 1 above) to the id of the store where you want this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of redirect the particular product page as home page is pretty good but you need to change the redirection URL while you are changing the product...

It is simple ->>>>>>>>
$this->redirect($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=123'));

But just use featured Category in your home page...

Module->Featured->Limit & enable..

Product->edit(particular product)->special->leave price field and fix start date and end date...

System->design->layout->home->edit->add featured module in content top set priority 1

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart 2.3

file catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php after

```
// Add rewrite to url class
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $this->url->addRewrite($this);
        }
```

insert

```
if ( !isset($this->request->get['_route_']) && !isset($this->request->get['route']))   {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
            $this->request->get['product_id'] = 42;
        }

if ( isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'common/home' ){
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
            $this->request->get['product_id'] = 42;

        }
```

You will need to change the product_id to the id of your product. e.g. `$this->request->get['product_id'] = 102;`