# use a specific product page as the website homepage

Tags: opencart

You answered a question here: [Product page as homepage in Opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801331/product-page-as-homepage-in-opencart)

This works, however I have remove my SEO url's from all my products by changing the setting on the store settings page in order to give a product ID so this will work. Is there a way to make this work without ruining the SEO url's?